# Convert a PKCS#8 private key to PEM in java

Tags: java, encryption, ssl, bouncycastle, pem

Hello everyone I'm trying to convert a PKCS#8 private key that I generate in my java program to a PEM encoded file.

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
JDKKeyPairGenerator.RSA keyPairGen = new JDKKeyPairGenerator.RSA();        
keyPairGen.initialize(2048, rand);
KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();

PEMWriter privatepemWriter = new PEMWriter(new FileWriter(new File(dir + "private.key")));
privatepemWriter.writeObject(keyPair.getPrivate());
```

After running the program I have the private key in both formats and a public key(the code isn't shown as it works). I then use this openssl command to conver the private.key back to a pem formated file.

```
openssl pkcs8 -nocrypt -inform DER -in private.key -out private2.pem
```

When I compare private.pem and private2.pem they are different and obviously when I try to use private.pem it says it's not a valid file.

What step am I missing in order to properly convert this private key into the PEM format that I need? I can't use OpenSSL from within my program, otherwise I would simply add that function call. I have access to BouncyCastle libs in this program, so maybe it has a solution I'm overlooking.

Comment: What software are you trying to inter-operate with? (When you say, "it says it's not a valid file," what is "it"?)

Comment: Curl and OpenSSL say the same thing when I try to use the private.key for various operations.

Comment: missing privatepemWriter.close(); // to flush correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [PEMWriter](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMWriter.html) class in Bouncycastle.

Comment: Thanks this worked out great and I was able to remove all of my redundant code! Reading the source code helped me figure out what objects to pass.
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Security/Bouncy-Castle/org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMWriter.java.htm

Answer (score 8):

The fact that OpenSSL uses it's own format is really the only thing that makes this challenging. Thankfully the bouncy castle PEMWriter makes this easy, but the interface isn't very well documented. I found some code by searching through the mailing list. I've adapted it below:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGen.initialize(2048);
KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair(); 
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
PEMWriter pemWriter = new PEMWriter(stringWriter);  
pemWriter.writeObject( keyPair.getPrivate());
pemWriter.close();
privateKeyString = stringWriter.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the header:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
```

… and the footer:

```
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Note that the "RSA" is left out—The Java code is using PKCS #8 encoding for the private key, and that encoding includes the algorithm.

The `openssl` command that you show is converting a standard PKCS #8 key in DER form to a proprietary OpenSSL key in PEM form. To keep the PKCS #8 format, but convert from DER to PEM, add the -topk8 option. Then the OpenSSL output should match what your Java code is producing.

If you need to produce the OpenSSL key, instead of PKCS #8, it's possible, but you'll have to create your own OpenSSL structure with the BouncyCastle ASN.1 library and encode that. Please clarify if that's what you need.

Comment: Yes what I want is to produce the OpenSSL key instead of the PKCS#8. I looked at the PEMWriter bellow, but I don't know if that will do what I need, given the conversion.

Comment: Would it hurt you to try it out and see?